# combo box that has district names as items and whose value are displayed in a textfield interms of the districts' code

Tags: java, swing

I want a text field to display codes of districts corresponding to the district name as selected by a user from a combo box in the same interface but it is returning only codes for the first and the last districts. What can i do? the codes and the names are in the same database.
Sample code used is below:

```
 private void STATIONSPopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {                                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:

  String  connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CRIME_RECORDS";
  String dbUser = "root";
  String dbPwd = "cfm";
  Connection conn;
  ResultSet rs;

  try{
     String tmp = (String)STATIONS.getSelectedItem();
     String sql ="select * from STATION_CODES where STATION_NAME = ?";
     PreparedStatement pst;    

     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

     conn= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, dbUser,dbPwd);
     pst=(PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);

     pst.setString(1, tmp);
     rs=pst.executeQuery();

     if(rs.next()){
       String n = rs.getString("CODE");
       CODE.setText(n);
     }                     
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. You're asking a question about how to display information in your JTextField selected from a JComboBox, and you've shown code, yet you've shown no code that relates to the JComboBox, to any listeners attached to the JComoBox or to the JTextField. Is it me? Am I completely misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to find the cause of your problem and to analyze why your application is returning only codes for the first and the last districts. As [Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels) already remarked, it seems like some relevant part of your code is missing?

For the user interface part of your question, I would consider using code like this example below:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852371/
 * combo-box-that-has-district-names-as-items-and-whose-value-are-displayed-in-a-te
 */
public class DistrictsGui {
    private static final District[] DISTRICTS = {
            new District("name 1", "code 1"), new District("name 2", "code 2"),
            new District("name 3", "code 3"), new District("name 4", "code 4"),
            new District("name 5", "code 5"), new District("name 6", "code 6")
    };

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new DistrictsGui().getStarted();
    }

    private void getStarted() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stack Overflow: districts");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JComboBox<District> districtComboBox = new JComboBox<>(DISTRICTS);
        final JTextField districtTextField = new JTextField("");

        frame.getContentPane().add(districtComboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(districtTextField, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        districtComboBox.addActionListener(e -> {
            final District selectedDistrict
                = (District) districtComboBox.getSelectedItem();
            districtTextField.setText(selectedDistrict.getCode());
        });

        // Select the first item in the combo box explicitly,
        // to initialize the text field too.
        districtComboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The `District` class could look like this:

```
public class District {
    private final String name;
    private final String code;

    public District(String name, String code) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```